# How to recover from losing all your /data/db

Tags: mongodb

We are using mongodb 3.0.2 and our system is managed via MMS
We discover the one of our new DEV environment lost all the content for the `/data/db` including the journals, logs and config file.

One thing is the the instance is still up and running in memory.

Does anyone has a solution on how to recover from this situation?

I tried a `db.fsyncLock()` that is supposed to flush to data into disk but no luck.

Comment: wtf how did you lose all physical data? Plus the mongodb will son exit with an assertion error when it tries to get data it has not got in LRU

Comment: You might have better luck on dba.se...

Comment: In answer to your question: the fsync will not actually help since it will only (if it could) download a small segment of your data. You could use some disk recovery software at best

Comment: @Sammaye I'm not _certain_ it would crash when trying to load some data. On my Linux box, `lsof` showed that MongoDB mmap all data files on start. At this point, removing their entry from the file-system does not have any impact on the running process -- as long as it tries not to open or create a new file. Some trivial experiments tend to confirm that (see my answer). But maybe things would be different in more complex use cases ?

Comment: @Sammaye You mean "permanent" ? Of course not, but at the very least MongoDB should be stable enough to "back up" the collections using `mongodump` for example. Once again, this is all from speculations and empirical observations...

Comment: @SylvainLeroux it's ok I had a brief moment of stupidity. I forgot how the file system will open the files, though I am not sure what would happen on a very large db but since this is a dev envo I don't think we need to care

Answer (score 2):

AFAICT, as the files are already opened/memmapped by MongoDB, [removing their entry from the filesystem](http://linux.die.net/man/3/unlink) will not prevent MongoDB to still use them (on Unix-like systems, at least). As long as they are not closed and that MongoDB do not need to open other files, things should still be usable. Enough to start doing some dumps.

As an experiment, I populated a newly installed MongoDB 3.0.2 instance with 2M documents. Stopping it, restarting it, and removing the `data` folder -- before having even accessed the collection. Finally I was able to `mongodump` that collection without any issue:

```
> for (i = 0; i < 2000000; ++i) { db.test.insert({x:i}) }
```

```
# Stop MongoDB
# Start MongoDB again

rm -rf data

mongodump -d test -c test 
# success !

# Stop MongoDB

mkdir -p data/db

# Start MongoDB again

mongorestore -d test -c test dump/test/test.bson
```

```
> db.test.count()
2000000
```

Comment: Yeah I see how this is possible now even if mmap is not residential memory, file system mechanics 101

Comment: Lost of physical date was lost of filesystem with no backup